# Why Spacy doesn't recognise all named entities in the label?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I am on Python 3.8 and using Spacy 2.3.5. I tried to use EntityRuler to assign a new label 'TH-T-MARKER' to a group of entities, and then to visualize them in displacy. Here's the code:

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Strings of target markers
targettext = """'T-bet+', 'IFN-γ+', 'TNF-α+',
'GATA-3+', 'IL-4+',
'PU.1+', 'IL-9+', 'IL-4–', 'IL-17–', 'IFN-γ–',
'CCR4+', 'CCR6+', 'CCR10–', 'RORγt+', 'IL-17+',
'CCR10+', 'AHR+', 'IL-22+', 'IL-17–', 'IFN-γ–',
'CXCR5+', 'ICOS+', 'PD-1+', 'Bcl-6+', 'IL-21+',
'CD25+', 'IL-2 Rα+', 'CD127-', 'IL-7 Rα–', 'IL-7 Rα low', 'FoxP3+'"""

ruler = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)

# List of target markers
tcell = [
'T-bet+', 'IFN-γ+', 'TNF-α+',
'GATA-3+', 'IL-4+',
'PU.1+', 'IL-9+', 'IL-4–', 'IL-17–', 'IFN-γ–',
'CCR4+', 'CCR6+', 'CCR10–', 'RORγt+', 'IL-17+',
'CCR10+', 'AHR+', 'IL-22+', 'IL-17–', 'IFN-γ–',
'CXCR5+', 'ICOS+', 'PD-1+', 'Bcl-6+', 'IL-21+',
'CD25+', 'IL-2 Rα+', 'CD127-', 'IL-7 Rα–', 'IL-7 Rα low', 'FoxP3+'
]

# create marker pattern
tcell_match = {
    'TEXT': {'IN': tcell}
}

# create entity pattern
tcell_pattern = {
    'label': 'TH-T-MARKER',
    'pattern': [tcell_match]
}

t_patterns = [tcell_pattern]


ruler.add_patterns(t_patterns)
# Add the Entity Ruler to the nlp pipeline
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)
LABELING_DATA = []
doc = nlp(targettext)

colors = {"TH-T-MARKER": "#5076BE"}
options = {"ents": ["TH-T-MARKER"], "colors": colors}
displacy.serve(doc, style='ent', options=options)
```

To make the problem clear, I simply copied and pasted all entities in the list 'tcell' into the 'targettext'. The result shows that among all the entities within the list 'tcell', only entities 'RORγt+','AHR+','ICOS+' and 'CD127-' are correctly assigned with the label "TH-T-MARKER".

I wonder if there is a way to make all the entities being labelled as "TH-T-MARKER"? Also I don't really understand why only part of the entities are labelled correctly, especially when the target text only contains the same strings as the name of entities in the pattern 'tcell_pattern'. Any thoughts on this problem would be so appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using spaCy v2?

The issue here is that because you've used the `{"TEXT":{"IN":{...}}` structure you're only matching single tokens. Because your targets have punctuation in them it's probably getting split into multiple tokens and therefore not matching.

One of the advantages of the EntityRuler is that you don't have to worry about how the tokenizer works if you just hand the pattern over. Here's how you can do that, in which case all your entities are matched:

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Strings of target markers
targettext = """'T-bet+', 'IFN-γ+', 'TNF-α+',
'GATA-3+', 'IL-4+',
'PU.1+', 'IL-9+', 'IL-4–', 'IL-17–', 'IFN-γ–',
'CCR4+', 'CCR6+', 'CCR10–', 'RORγt+', 'IL-17+',
'CCR10+', 'AHR+', 'IL-22+', 'IL-17–', 'IFN-γ–',
'CXCR5+', 'ICOS+', 'PD-1+', 'Bcl-6+', 'IL-21+',
'CD25+', 'IL-2 Rα+', 'CD127-', 'IL-7 Rα–', 'IL-7 Rα low', 'FoxP3+'"""

ruler = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)

# List of target markers
tcell = [
'T-bet+', 'IFN-γ+', 'TNF-α+',
'GATA-3+', 'IL-4+',
'PU.1+', 'IL-9+', 'IL-4–', 'IL-17–', 'IFN-γ–',
'CCR4+', 'CCR6+', 'CCR10–', 'RORγt+', 'IL-17+',
'CCR10+', 'AHR+', 'IL-22+', 'IL-17–', 'IFN-γ–',
'CXCR5+', 'ICOS+', 'PD-1+', 'Bcl-6+', 'IL-21+',
'CD25+', 'IL-2 Rα+', 'CD127-', 'IL-7 Rα–', 'IL-7 Rα low', 'FoxP3+'
]

patterns = [{"label": "TH-T-MARKER", "pattern": tt} for tt in tcell]

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
# Add the Entity Ruler to the nlp pipeline
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)
LABELING_DATA = []
doc = nlp(targettext)

colors = {"TH-T-MARKER": "#5076BE"}
options = {"ents": ["TH-T-MARKER"], "colors": colors}
displacy.serve(doc, style='ent', options=options)
```